# how to put the address box to the right side to my name in CV

Tags: horizontal-alignment, color, tcolorbox, cv, addresses

I am using Cies Breijs template and I would like to have a box like this at the right corner of my CV.[image] This box is taken from 'two coloumn cv' template.

But, what I am getting is something like this[image]

This is the code I'm using

```
\documentclass[10t,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}

% Setup the language.
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hyphenation{Some-long-word}

% Makes resume-specific commands available.
\usepackage{resume}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\usepackage{marvosym}
%\usepackage[big]{layaureo} 
\usepackage{supertabular}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}
\definecolor{royalblue(traditional)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.14, 0.4}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%-------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}  % begin the content of the document
\sloppy  % this to relax whitespacing in favour of straight margins

\definecolor{oxfordblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.13, 0.28}  
% title on top of the document
\maintitle{\huge
{\scalebox{1}[1.1]{\color{royalblue(traditional)}Sathy Harshavardhan 
Reddy}}}{May 03, 1994}{Last update on \today}

\nobreakvspace{1em}  % add some page break averse vertical spacing

% \noindent prevents paragraph's first lines from indenting
% \mbox is used to obfuscate the email address
% \sbull is a spaced bullet
% \href well..
% \\ breaks the line into a new paragraph
\newcommand\personal[4][]{%
\needspace{0.5\textheight}%
\newdimen\boxwidth%
\boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
\colorbox[HTML]{F5DD9D }{%
\begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c|X}
\Writinghand & {#2}\smallskip\\
\Telefon     & {#3}\smallskip\\
\Letter      & \href{mailto:#4}{#4}
\ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \Lightning & \href{http://#1}{#1}}
\end{tabularx}}}

\personal
[www.entidi.com]
{viale Conciliazione, 13\newline 25039 -- Travagliato (BS)}
{+39 (30) 6862332}
{ntd@entidi.it}
```

Can somebody help me in anyway?

Comment: How is this different from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383388/117534?

Comment: The cited question is gone.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north east)}]
\node[align=left,anchor=north east]{Me Myself\\
100 Center Street\\
Hometown};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page text area.north east)}]
\node[align=left]{Me Myself\\
    100 Center Street\\
    Hometown};
\end{tikzpicture}



\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I need that coloured box as such.